# Showing database amount field and adding it with a textbox data and storing it in database using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks, entity

I have a amount field in database Account_Holder I want to add value to it

Comment: Show us what you have done. we wont do homework for you!

Comment: It is difficult for me to do so... Please help tell me how to update using entity framework

Comment: you have to declare your context, map the data, and then add the object to your context, and call SaveChanges().

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var context = new MyEntities();
var myObject = new myObjectType();
myObject.myValue = myTextBox.Text;
context.myObjectTypes.Add(myObject);
context.SaveChanges();
```